# Can a strong athletic girl help Isa (Jesus) in his fight against Dajjal?

Tags: women, prophet-isa, dajjal

Salam. 
I am a 14 year old girl and I wanted to ask if I could join hazrat Isa (AS) with his fight with Dajjal.
Actually I researched if women will participate in that war but couldn't find any relevant answers.
  I have won in arm wrestling from all the girls and almost half of the boys, lost from 3 and the others I don't communicate with much so it would have been quite weird if I was like hey u wanna challenge Popeye the sailor man!
 I also win every basket ball match and everyone wants me on their team. I can do about 50 push ups non stop and work out daily. I am also planning on working on my physical fitness more after I graduate.
So lets just say if women weren't allowed, would it be ok if I joined in as a man. I mean I could stick fake beard and wear men clothes. I can work on my voice and all my other attributes are not quite different then those of men. For example the walking style, no drama or gossip or shopping or makeup, I like action and don't cry much or whine.
 Would it be haram if I joined hazrat Isa's army that way. I mean I just want to help him.
 I can imagine my picture made in your mind but trust me despite being a tomboy, I am also a very good shy religious girl among people who make fun of me for being so committed to Islam. It hurts but I'm proud of it.

Comment: No, because it will be 1'o'1. ;)

Comment: sorry what would be this thing.

Comment: no for what. is it possible. r women allowed

Comment: First who said that Isa (peace be upon) him will fight Dajjal or lead the fighting? Second you should know that scholars say it's prohibited for a woman to act or wear like a man? Third i never heard that it was allowed for women to fight but maybe if you are as strong as or stronger then a male that could be a qualification! But generally women were kind of nurses or so for the fighters!

Comment: first, i am really sorry for speaking with incomplete knowledge. second, i only meant to act/dress like a man for the sake of this specific battle. third, i know you're right anyway, from top to bottom, and i'm wrong, but your "!!!!2 seem to punch me in the face. now i don't mind( because i know of my stupidness) but there might be many more stupid people out there  trying to learn so please compromise.......

Comment: @rameen Mashallah sister :D We need this spirit in our youth. As Islam honors women, it is always preferred to keep them safe and sound. They can always contribute in the backlines of the army as Medi1Saif said as nurses or logistics coordinators for example. I appreciate your enthusiasm, but wars are usually hell, and even the strongest and toughest of men both physically and mentally break down sometimes. Maybe if you live in actual war conditions you'd change your mind :P (...)

Comment: @rameen (...) As for the great war, it will be a huge war between 2 armies, and if you are seen fit by whomever the commander is (when that time comes, and if it comes during your lifetime) then you can join the army. There's no rule here, it's a decision the commanders make. But in general, women are put in the front lines only if it's necessary, as Islam insists on honoring and protecting women. (...)

Comment: @rameen (...) On the other hand, don't believe what you hear from people, that women should be weak and soft and (bla bla bla ...).
[Check this out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nene_Hatun). There are many other example of such women which I read about but don't remember their names... As a Muslim, be at your best at all times, and leave the conditions to whatever Allah decides for you. Mashallah :D

Answer (score 1):

First of all, allow me to congratulate you on pursuing your strength and your enthusiasm in wanting to lend a hand to Issa.

Second, allow me to point out the sexism in your sentence that, even if I am sure is not wanted, can be hurtful to some: saying "I don't whine and gossip" while implying that these are female "attributes" is a bit uncalled for. Make up does not make you a woman and no "walking style" can make you a man. Saying these things can be hurtful, I bet as hurtful as someone making fun of you "being so committed to Islam". Consider others' feelings.

Now regarding your question:

Contrary to what @Medi1Saif said, according to Islam, Issa (Jesus) will indeed come back and lead the fight against Dajjal.
And as @Zia says in his/her comment, it will be "one on one". There would be an army, but it is on the side of Dajjal. Jesus will simply look at him, and Dajjal will "dissolve into salt" (see [one of the many accounts](http://www.usc.edu/org/cmje/religious-texts/hadith/muslim/041-smt.php#041.7023), to my knowledge, there is no contradictory account saying that Issa would assemble an army from the people living at the time of his arrival. You can google "Dajjal Isa Fight Jesus" for more information.

I don't think you can go "Mulan-style".

Comment: My skepticism against that statement comes from my knowledge about this hadith http://sunnah.com/bukhari/60/119 which shows that there will be an Imam who will lead the Muslims. Personaly i don't care about those ahadith about Dajjal etc. as too many of them seem to be fabricated!

Comment: That is also a defensible point (the fabricated one). I now understand your confusion and realize that @rameen may also be confused: there *would* be a leader (called Mahdi) but he is not the same as Isa. Mahdi would appear first, and then Isa. So you are right in saying that Isa doesn't really "lead" any fight. Rameen, maybe you could rewrite your question ?

Comment: Please go through this [page](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) to learn how to address properly.

Comment: @ZakariaChihani thanks for your support but i wasn't confused. i really did think jesus would fight because i always heard of an ARMY not knowing it was only on dajjal's side but yeah now i'm thinking of joining mr mahdi's side so thanks. at the end i'm really sorry for all the ***ism. i didn't mean to offend anyone i was just being practical. i cant explain it in a better way because i am never able to make people understand my point anyway so rewriting wont help.

Answer (score 0):

As other have mentioned, the battle between Isa (AS) and Dajjal would be one on one. Also no one except Isa/Jesus will be able to kill the Dajjal/AntiChrist.

> Narrated Ibn Umar:
>
> Umar set out along with the Prophet (p.b.u.h) with a group of people
>   to Ibn Saiyad till they saw him playing with the boys near the
>   hillocks of Bani Mughala. 
> Ibn Saiyad at that time was nearing his
>   puberty and did not notice (us) until the Prophet (ﷺ) stroked him with
>   his hand and said to him, "Do you testify that I am Allah's Messenger
>   (ﷺ)?"
>  Ibn Saiyad looked at him and said, "I testify that you are the
>   Messenger of illiterates."
>  Then Ibn Saiyad asked the Prophet
>   (p.b.u.h), "Do you testify that I am Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)?" 
> The
>   Prophet (p.b.u.h) refuted it and said, "I believe in Allah and His
>   Apostles."
>  Then he said (to Ibn Saiyad), "What do you think?"
>  Ibn
>   Saiyad answered, "True people and liars visit me." 
> The Prophet (ﷺ)
>   said, "You have been confused as to this matter."
>  Then the Prophet (ﷺ)
>   said to him, "I have kept something (in my mind) for you, (can you
>   tell me that?)" 
> Ibn Saiyad said, "It is Al-Dukh (the smoke)." 
>  The
>   Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Let you be in ignominy. You cannot cross your
>   limits."
>  On that **Umar, said, "O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! Allow me to
>   chop his head off."
>
>  The Prophet (p.b.u.h) said, "If he is he (i.e.
>   Dajjal), then you cannot overpower him, and if he is not, then there
>   is no use of murdering him.**" 
> (Ibn Umar added): Later on Allah's
>   Messenger (ﷺ) (p.b.u.h) once again went along with Ubai bin Kab to
>   the date-palm trees (garden) where Ibn Saiyad was staying. The Prophet
>   (p.b.u.h) wanted to hear something from Ibn Saiyad before Ibn Saiyad
>   could see him, and the Prophet (p.b.u.h) saw him lying covered with a
>   sheet and from where his murmurs were heard.
>  Ibn Saiyad's mother saw
>   Allah's Apostle while he was hiding himself behind the trunks of the
>   date-palm trees. She addressed Ibn Saiyad, "O Saf ! (and this was the
>   name of Ibn Saiyad) Here is Muhammad." And with that Ibn Saiyad got
>   up. 
> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Had this woman left him (Had she not
>   disturbed him), then Ibn Saiyad would have revealed the reality of his
>   case.
>   [Sahih al-Bukhari, Book 23, Hadith 109](https://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/23/109)

I would also recommend you to read on another set of Hadiths which show the extend of Dajjal's power on women being so strong that the father, husband and brothers would be advised to tie their women inside their house to protect the imaan of their ladies. Even many believing men who have faith in Allah will to confront him but he will out of the powers that Allah blessed him with will make them believe that he (Dajjal) is actually God.

May Allah protect us all from the fitnah of the AntiChrist. Ameen